# Assembly uses AspNetIdentity.EntityFramework Version 2.0. 0 which has a higher version than the referenced version 1.0.0

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity

```
Error   2   Assembly 'Online_Store.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'    c:\Users\postgres\Desktop\Online_Tan\Online_Store2013\Online_Store.Infrastructure\bin\Debug\Online_Store.Infrastructure.dll OnlineStore_Commercial
```

Here is my problem:

I'm making an online store and I want my OnlineStoreDBContext to inherit `IdentityDbContext` and that's why I have to use Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework library! But no matter how many times I start from beggining and delete the whole Online_Store.Infrastructure class library I get the same error

```
public class OnlineStoreDBContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>

{
    public OnlineStoreDBContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Language> Languages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CategoryLanguages> CategoryLanguages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductLanguages> ProductLanguages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductCategories> ProuctCategories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderDetails> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }







}
```

Comment: In your project references open the NuGet Manager and go to updates tab.  Apply any updates that are available and see if your error goes away. If this project references other projects in a solution make sure they are up to date as well.

Comment: Yes everything is OK -> there are no updates! Itt just drives me crazy

Comment: Somehow in your binaries, you have a 'Online_Store.Infrastructure' assembly that references the old Identity assembly. You can check assembly resolution with a tool like Fuslogvw.exe: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e74a18c4(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Delete references to `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` in all your projects and add them again, make sure they have `2.0.0.0` version. Check version of .net framework you are targeting, should be the same in all projects.

Comment: Try adding binding redirect in the web.config for Identity.EntityFramework package

Comment: I got the same error. Updating NuGet packages solved the error. Thanks @KevinJunghans

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried nuking the packages folder in your solution?  If you delete that directory and let nuget pull in fresh versions of all the packages, that might take care of any weird behavior you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

You can add binding to redirect the request for old version to newer one like this

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
     </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the `project / solution` files in edit mode and check from where 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework' is being referred from.